# Can't click on web element with flutter appium driver that is covered by other element

Tags: flutter, appium, flutter-web, flutter-test

I tried to test a webview in flutter app using flutter appium driver and faced a problem:
In a webview I have a text, that is placed in two lines. Because of that placing text is covered by another element. 
I tried 3 approaches:

**1.appium driver: mouse.moveTo then mouse.click.**
Solution with mouse.moveTo then mouse.click did not work because appium need other parametr called duration, that is not included to parameters in our appium_driver.

**2. Used flutter inspector to locate elements on the webview** - solution was not succeed because this webviews are external and were not covered by any flutter overlay.

**3. Clicking by bounds**
Got all objects from the webview with TESTWorld().appiumDriver.pageSource. Found out that we have the xml with all objects on webview with properties as bounds,text. Made a list with 3 objects of “MyString“ string and clicked on them one by one with click() method from appium_driver. Second element “MyString“ is clickable, appium can click on it, but first instance of this string is in two lines, so this element is part of other big element, that’s why appium_driver can’t click on it.

Maybe someone knows another approach?

Answer (score 0):

> Because of that placing text is covered by another element

In a particular case, it sounds like an AUT issue. Appium uses WebDriver API for testing WebView and it is expected to not be able to interact with the overlapped element.

If there is no way to address and fix it in the app, you can try JS to send a click action (the same way we do in Webdriver):

```
WebElement textElement = driver.findElement(...);
JavascriptExecutor jsEx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsEx.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", textElement);
```